# How to extract the embedded video from a Samsung's Motion Photo jpeg file

Tags: video, photo

Some Samsung smartphones have a feature called [Motion photo](http://www.samsung.com/global/galaxy/what-is/motion-photo/).

With normal photo viewers you cannot play the embedded video.

How can you extract the video to play it with a normal video player?

NOTE: self-answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `exiftool`:

`sudo apt install libimage-exiftool-perl`

Extract the video:

`exiftool -b -EmbeddedVideoFile my_motion_photo.jpg >video.mp4`